# What's 'D' stands for on the numbers of MSC Nastran .f06 output file?

Tags: nastran

I performed flutter analysis using MSC Nastran, and I want to extract the generalized aerodynamic matrix, which is Qhh in the .f06 output file.

I have kinda succeeded, but as shown in the figure, the numbers include 'D', not 'E', which is quite new to me.

[Part of Nastran Output .f06 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb8Yf.jpg)

Does anyone have a idea what this 'D' in the number stands for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

E = exponential notation (SINGLE PRECISION)

D = DOUBLE PRECISION

Those are two ways to store REAL numbers in memory.

DOUBLE PRECISION numbers usually have at least twice the number of significant decimal digits.

You can read more here: [fortran_datatype](https://www.obliquity.com/computer/fortran/datatype.html)